# Evaluating Double Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\iint_{S} (x^3+y^3)\,dy\,dz + (z^3+y^3)\,dz\,dx + (x^3+z^3)\,dx\,dy$$ where $S$ is the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2= a^2$.

Spherical coordinates help me in this question, $r^2=a^2$.

We can also write $$\iiint_{S} 2(x^3+y^3+z^3)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ or not?

Thank you for your advanced ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Mikhail Ostrogradsky a surface integral can be converted to volume integral where P, Q, R are function of x, y, z.

$$\iint_SP\mathop{dy}\mathop{dz} + Q\mathop{dz}\mathop{dx} + R\mathop{dx}\mathop{dy} = \iiint_V(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial R}{\partial z})\mathop{dx}\mathop{dy}\mathop{dz}$$

Hence the surface integral becomes

$$\iiint_V(3x^2 + 3y^2 + 3z^2)dx\mathop{dy}\mathop{dz}$$
$$= 3\iiint_V r^2\mathop{dx}\mathop{dy}\mathop{dz}$$
$$= 3\int_{0}^{a}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi} r^4cos\phi \mathop{d\theta}\mathop{d\phi}\mathop{dr}$$
$$= 6\pi \int_{0}^{a}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} r^4cos\phi \mathop{d\phi}\mathop{dr}$$
$$= 12\pi \int_{0}^{a} r^4 \mathop{dr}$$
$$= \frac{12}{5}\pi a^5$$

Comment: You are right.  I am making an edit.  Thanks.

Comment: Note you can use `\iint_S` $\iint_S$ and `\iiint_V` $\iiint_V$ for multidimensional integrals, it renders better than succession of `\int\int` $\int\int$

Comment: This is good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 For Ostrogradsky :).